# Minute data not working zipline

Tags: python, zipline, back-testing

I wanted to get some minute history data by using the following:

```
 hist_minutes = data.history(context.aapl,'price',50,'1m')
```

This gave me the following error:

```
NoDataForSid:No minute data for sid 2509.
```

This is strange because when I used 1d instead of 1m it did work, so why is that? And how can this be fixed in order to also get minute data.

Answer (score 0):

What data are you using? If you ingested the default [Quandl bundle](http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html#default-data-bundles), that dataset in particular only has daily prices, and does not have minutely prices. You'll need to gather your own minutely data and either [write a new bundle](http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html#writing-a-new-bundle) or [ingest csv files](http://www.zipline.io/bundles.html#ingesting-data-from-csv-files).

If you want to use anything that's not US equity daily pricing, you'll need your own data.

Source / Disclaimer: I'm a Zipline maintainer.